# concat in condition left join active record codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a problem with active record codeigniter ver 2 wih special criteria like this:

```
$this->db->select('t_po_detail_item, t_process_shif, m_machine_lines, m_machine_mac, t_po_detail_no,
                       t_prod_lot, CONCAT(t_prod_lot, "-", t_prod_sublot) AS nolot,
                       COUNT(t_prod_sublot) AS qtybox, SUM(t_process_qty) AS qtypcs,
                       ROUND((SUM(t_process_qty)*m_process_weight)/1000,1) AS qtyberat', FALSE);
    $this->db->join(self::$table2, 't_process_prod_id = t_prod_id', 'left')
             ->join(self::$table3, 't_prod_lot = t_po_detail_lot_no', 'left')
             ->join(self::$table5, 't_process_machine = m_machine_id', 'left')
             ->join(self::$table4, 'CONCAT_WS("-",t_po_detail_item, t_process_cat) = CONCAT_WS("-",m_process_id, m_process_proc_cat_id)', 'left');
    $this->db->where('t_process_cat', 16);
    $this->db->group_by('nolot');
    $query  = $this->db->get(self::$table1);
```

there are have special criteria join condition with concat WS. If i use standard query mysql, the query is running ok.

```
$sql = 'SELECT t_po_detail_item, t_process_shif, m_machine_lines, m_machine_mac, t_po_detail_no, t_prod_lot, CONCAT_WS("-",t_prod_lot, t_prod_sublot) AS nolot,
            COUNT(t_prod_sublot) AS qtybox, SUM(t_process_qty) AS qtypcs, ROUND((SUM(t_process_qty)*m_process_weight)/1000,1) AS qtyberat
            FROM `t_process`
            LEFT JOIN t_prod ON t_process_prod_id = t_prod_id
            LEFT JOIN t_po_detail ON t_prod_lot = t_po_detail_lot_no
            LEFT JOIN m_machine ON t_process_machine = m_machine_id
            LEFT JOIN m_process ON CONCAT_WS("-",t_po_detail_item, t_process_cat) = CONCAT_WS("-",m_process_id, m_process_proc_cat_id)
            WHERE t_process_cat=16
            GROUP BY(nolot)';

    $query  = $this->db->query($sql);
```

There are wrong in my active record code ?
regards,

Neos.

Comment: Try $this->db->last_query(); and check difference in query

Comment: still error ..where position this code ?

Answer (score 0):

When using MySQL functions inside Codeigniter query builder, you need functions to be outside quotes `""`, so you need to pass an optional fourth parameter to join, which says rather to escape the inputs or not, and your query becomes,

```
$this->db->join($table, $condition, $join_type, false);
```

Read more here: [CI Docs - Query Builder](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: i use`$this->db->join($table, $condition, $join_type, false);` but still error